# How to model relation over 3 entity types with Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I cannot figure out how to model this in Firestore: I have ***Users***, ***Lists*** and ***Tasks***. *Users* can be in multiple *Lists* and each *Task* is in one *List*.

How do I model my data so that I can create a query that returns all *Tasks* that are related to a single *User*? In other words: Given a *User* I want wo query all *Tasks* that belong to any *List* where that *User* is in. Please note that I also want to listen to realtime updates on that query.

Comment: A Firestore query can't use documents from multiple collections in a single query.  There are no SQL-like joins.  You will need to create a collection that has all the information you need for the query.  Sometimes that involves duplicating data across collections, and that's a common strategy for nosql type databases.  It's call "denormalization".

Comment: I only want the Tasks to be returned and they can be all in the same collection. Also there are group collection queries that allow querying  documents from multiple collections with one query.

Comment: Collection group queries require that all collections have the same name, which might be kind of awkward for this case.